# How to access the current request while in an domain object used by requestfactory?

Tags: java, gwt, requestfactory

I am using GWT RequestFactory. 
When I am in a normal RPC class that extends RemoteServiceServlet I can access the current request using `this.getThreadLocalRequest()`.

Now I am in a Domain object. How can I access the current request?
I need to get `getThreadLocalRequest().getRemoteUser()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similarly: [`RequestFactoryServlet.getThreadLocalRequest()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/requestfactory/server/RequestFactoryServlet.html#getThreadLocalRequest%28%29)`.getRemoteUser()`